# Load mixed assembly at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a project uses Sqlite (`System.Data.SQLite.DLL`) it is mixed assembly. I need to load it at runtime. As I know it impossible using `AssemblyResolve` event. So the target is to unpack assembly to Temp directory and show to application where to find it.
The code is:

```
public static void SaveSqlite()
{
    byte[] sqliteAsm = EmbedAssembly.System_Data_SQLite;
    string tempFile = Path.GetTempPath();
    File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile + "System.Data.SQLite.DLL", sqliteAsm);
}

// and the setup int start method

SaveSqlite();
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = Path.GetTempPath();
```

So it not works. Application cant find sqlite assembly but it successfuly saved to Temp dir. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an exception?

Comment: The private bin path must be under the application's base directory, otherwise it is ignored. Also, you cannot modify the `AppDomainSetup` data after the application domain has been created. The data is only read when creating a new app domain. If it is modified after creation those changes are ignored.

Comment: Yes. Application says it cant find assembly System.Data.SQLite.DLL

Comment: mike z. Ok. but is it possible some way load assembly from Temp?

Answer (score 0):

The solution has founded.

1. Not using mixed assembly but managed for sqlite interop Using
   SQLite.
2. SQLite.Interop.dll - native dll (unpack to any directory)
3. Call `SetDllDirectory` WinAPI to set dll search directory

code for extract sqlite native dll from resource looks like that:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

//...
string text4 = Path.Combine(text, "SQLite.Interop.dll");
                if (!File.Exists(text4))
                {
                    byte[] array3 = LoadCompressedDllFromResource("nativedll.SQLite.Interop.z");
                    array3 = DecompressBytes(array3);
                    SaveToFile(array3, text4);
                }
//...
```

pack all over managed assemblies using **libz** application